# Problem with bending model using simple deform

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, modifiers, system

I'm trying to create a wallet case in blender, I want to add a system that allows me to comfortably "adjust" one slider to open, close and flip it. Currently I divided the case into two movable parts, the 1st one, that bends, uses simple deform. However I can't figure out a way, to have the 2nd one "connect" to it so that it moves with the middle section, but doesn't bend. At the moment when I slide the angle slider in simple deform I only move the middle section. For now, the 2nd part compensates by using simple keyframes but that's a very inaccurate and slow method. So I'd like to know, is there any way to connect the two, and have simple deform or any other system perform all the work?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [vertex parenting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#make-vertex-parent), which is similar to parenting but the child will follow the vertices as they are deformed.

1. Select the cover.
2. Shift select the spine.
3. Go into edit mode.
4. Select three vertices a the end of the spine.
5. Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to parent the selected object/s to the selected vertices.

[image: vertex parent]

[image: sample result]